# FullCalendar switch between weekends and no weekends

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I was wondering if there was a way in Arshaw's FullCalendar to:
1- Change the calendar from showing weekends to not show weekends and vice versa.
2- To dynamically change the timeslot interval from say 30 minutes to 60 minutes.

In other words, what I am trying to do is:

```
//Clicking the button that shows Saturday and Sunday too
    $('#weekend-yes').click(function(){
        $('#weekend-yes').hide();
        $('#weekend-no').fadeIn();
            //HYPOTHETICALLY  DO THIS
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'weekends', true/false);
    });
```

If something like that is not possible, what would be the best workaround? I guess I could have a second calendar which is a replica of the first, but that would be too much replication.

Appreciate any help I can get..

Comment: Per the author of this plugin, all the FullCalendar options don't have setters (unfortunately weekends is one of them). So I think you have a couple of options - 1) reinit (destroy and init) the calendar with weekends set to true/false or 2) edit the source for the plugin to add a setter for this option. I have seen issues logged around this, but I don't think this plugin is actively developed anymore. All the best!

Comment: Your suggestion to destroy and re-init worked great..How do I convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: Glad it worked! Adding my comment as an answer! :)

Comment: FullCalendar added a weekend setter in 2.9.0 (7-10-2016), so no calendar destroy or custom view manipulation is necessary anymore. See my solution for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the author of this plugin, all the FullCalendar options don't have setters (unfortunately `weekends` is one of them). So I think you have a couple of options

1. reinit (destroy and init) the calendar with weekends set to true/false
2. edit the source for the plugin to add a setter for this option. I have seen issues logged around this, but I don't think this plugin is actively developed anymore.

All the best!

Comment: FullCalendar added a weekend setter in 2.9.0 (7-10-2016), so no calendar destroy or custom view manipulation is necessary anymore. See my solution for more details.

Comment: @gregblass thanks for updating. Maybe you can edit my answer with yours, so people coming here in future get the information on top?

Comment: Yeah I mean, obviously I'm biased :) but I do feel like my answer should now be the accepted one. It also shows how to add a control to the calendar header that toggles the text as well.

Comment: I agree. Open-source libraries do change and FC has gone through a complete redesign.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
$('#values').click(function(){
    var weekend = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'weekends');
    if (weekend){
        $('#values').text('Show weekend');
        $('.fc-header').remove();
        $('.fc-content').remove();
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ firstDay:1, height:650, 
                                           weekMode:'liquid', weekends:false, 
                                           header: {left: 'prev,next today', 
                                                    center: 'title',
                                                    right: 'month,
                                                    agendaWeek,agendaDay'}});
    } else {
        $('#values').text('Hide weekend');
        $('.fc-header').remove();
        $('.fc-content').remove();
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ firstDay:1, height:650, 
                               weekMode:'liquid', weekends:true, 
                               header: {left: 'prev,next today',
                                        center: 'title',
                                         right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'}});
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update for 2017:** FullCalendar added a weekend setter in 2.9.0 (7-10-2016), so no calendar destroy or custom view manipulation is necessary anymore.

Here's how I implemented a weekend toggle in my production app using FullCalendar 3.1.0:

```
var calendarOptions = {
  ...
  customButtons: {
    toggleWeekends: {
      text: 'Show Weekends',
      click: function() {
        toggleWeekends();
      },
    },
  },
  ...
  header: {
    left: 'today toggleWeekends',
    ...
  },
  weekends: false,
}

function toggleWeekends() {
  var weekends = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'weekends');
  var text = 'Show Weekends';

  if (weekends == false) {
    text = 'Hide Weekends';
  }

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', {
    customButtons: {
      toggleWeekends: {
        text: text,
        click: function() {
          toggleWeekends();
        },
      },
    },
    weekends: !weekends,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Old topic but still is not solved with current implementation of fullCalendar (2 & 3). 
fullCalendar has feature '**changeView**'. 
You have to customize view. You can do this by extending one of existing.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
views: {
    workWeek: {
        type: 'agendaWeek',
        hiddenDays: [0, 6]
    }
}});
```

Right now you can change view any time you need.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'workWeek' )
```

or

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'agendaWeek' )
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this on google and figured I would add an option not mentioned already. The calendar days all have a css class with their name, making them easy to target.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#toggleOff').on('click', function(){
       $('.fc-sat').hide();
       $('.fc-sun').hide();
   });

   $('#toggleOn').on('click', function(){
       $('.fc-sat').show();
       $('.fc-sun').show();
   });
});
```

Comment: I went with this solution, but the business-hours-background would not toggle. You also have to toggle `.fc-bgevent-skeleton td:eq(dow)`, in my case i ended up with the following one-liner:
`$(".fc-sat, .fc-sun, .fc-bgevent-skeleton td:eq(6), .fc-bgevent-skeleton td:eq(7)").toggle();`

Comment: This misaligns the day numbers. Not a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hope below code snippet might help you (I am using fullcalendar.js version 2)

```
var calendarInitiate = function(noWeekend){
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('destroy');
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({weekends:noWeekend, events: [{ ...enter events list here... }]});
}
calendarInitiate(true); //True initially to show weekends

$("#showWeekends").click(function(){ calendarInitiate(true); //This will show weekends });
$("#hideWeekends").click(function(){ calendarInitiate(false); //This will hide weekends });
```

Comment: Version 2 allows for this but it wasn't out when I posted the question

Answer (score 0):

For toggling weekends:

1. Create a [Custom View](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/)
2. Set [weekends](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/weekends/) to false in the custom view's properties
3. Add the name of your custom view to your [header](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/header/), so that a button will appear for this view.
4. Use [defaultView](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/defaultView/) to set the your initial view

---

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    //defaultView: 'agendaWeekdays',
    header: {
        right: 'month,monthWeekdays,agendaWeek,agendaWeekdays'
    },
    views: {
        agendaWeekdays: {
            buttonText: 'Weekdays',
            type: 'agendaWeek',
            weekends: false
        },
        monthWeekdays: {
            buttonText: 'Month (Weekdays)',
            type: 'month',
            weekends: false
        }
    }
});
```

---

As for slot duration, you could [destroy](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/destroy/) the calendar and create it again with the [slotDuration](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/slotDuration/) property changed.

Alternatively, you could create more Custom Views, each with different slotDurations. You wouldn't need to add buttons for these views to the header but instead create your own UI for slot duration that calls your custom views.

---

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaWeekdaysSlotDuration15');
```