# jQuery Full Calendar - How to prevent user from adding an event in non-business hours?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fullcalendar

jQuery Full Calendar - How to prevent user adding an event in non-business hours? Also the background color of the non-business hours should be grayed out or any custom color to be applied.

Example: My Business hours are: 9am - 1pm & 3pm to 7pm. [2 hour break should be there from 1pm - 3pm]

Code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
theme: true,
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
eventClick: updateEvent,
selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
select: selectDate,
editable: true,
events: "JsonResponse.ashx",
eventDrop: eventDropped,
eventResize: eventResized,
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    //alert(event.title);
    element.qtip({
        content: {
            text: qTipText(event.start, event.end, event.description),
            title: '<strong>' + event.title + '</strong>'
        },
        position: {
            my: 'bottom left',
            at: 'top right'
        },
        style: { classes: 'qtip-shadow qtip-rounded' }
    });
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958479/fullcalendar-switch-between-weekends-and-no-weekends

Comment: The above link is only for sat & sun, whereas i need to disable the click event / disable non business hours from mon - fri. Eg. My Business hours are: 9am - 1pm & 3pm to 7pm mon - fri. [2 hour break should be there from 1pm - 3pm].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to make it work you can add rules "if" to your **function selectDate** in the **calendarscript.js** file.

I set the working hours to 9AM till 5PM  , Monday till Friday in my example.

So first you check if the day "**start.format("ddd")**" is not Saturday or sunday , if true go to next if else show message.

Then you check if the start time "**start.format("HH")**"is smaller then 09 "9AM" or bigger then 16 "4PM" if true show message if false go the next if to check end time.

if end time "**end.format("HH")**" is bigger then 17 "5PM" show message or else go to the last if to check if it ends at 5PM.

So in the last if you check if end time is 17 "5PM" and minutes is not bigger then 00 open dialog , else show message.

Just replace the code **function selectDate** in the **calendarscript.js** file with the code below and the have working hours 9AM till 5PM

```
function selectDate(start, end, allDay) {
if (start.format("ddd") !== "Sat" && start.format("ddd") !== "Sun")
{
    if (start.format("HH") < 09 || start.format("HH") > 16) {
        alert("We are closed at that time , Please select a other time , 9 to 5");
        //alert(start.format("HH"));
    }
    else if (end.format("HH") > 17) {
        alert("We are closed at that time , Please select a other time , 9 to 5");
        //alert(start.format("mm"));
    }
    else if (end.format("HH") == 17 && end.format("mm") > 00) {
        alert("We are closed at that time , Please select a other time , 9 to 5");
        //alert(start.format("mm"));
    }
    else {
        $('#addDialog').dialog('open');
        $("#addEventStartDate").text("" + start.toLocaleString());
        $("#addEventEndDate").text("" + end.toLocaleString());

        addStartDate = start;
        addEndDate = end;
        globalAllDay = allDay;
        //alert(allDay);
    }      
}
else
{
    alert("We are close on Saturdays and Sundays");
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'll try the above code & revert immediately.

Comment: Appreciate your help. One small change, I wana add a dropdown with static minutes time slots i.e. 15/30/45/60. Now, when i click on save it should add the selected value from the dropdown to the starttime. $("#addEventStartDate").text("" + start.toLocaleString()); + 30 mins (e.g.) Simply append the time with the selected value from the dropdown. Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe better make a new question  so you can explain better what you want to do.

Answer (score 5):

I know it is too late but i haven't see the correct answer so this could be helpful, It's very simple use `selectConstraint` and `eventConstraint` options to prevent click event in non business hours (from full calendar 2.2version).
in my case i used `selectConstraint: "businessHours"` 
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectConstraint/
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventConstraint/

Comment: Thanks, this is the most efficient answer and way to achieve the wanted results!

Answer (score 2):

Just add these options in calendar code

```
businessHours: {
  // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
     daysOfWeek: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], // Monday - Thursday

     startTime: '10:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
     endTime: '18:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
 },
 selectConstraint: "businessHours",
```

Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can check where it contains business hour class or not like this:

```
// If it is not a business hour
if (jsEvent.target.classList.contains('fc-nonbusiness') || 
     jsEvent.target.classList.contains('busy-time')) {
                return;
}
else{
   // Do something if it is a business hour
}
```

Hopefully It will work  :)

Answer (score 0):

Use businessHours property to set certain time slots on the calendar. By default, Monday-Friday, 9am-5pm.

```
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
   businessHours : {
        start: '10:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
        end: '18:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)

        dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
        // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
        // (Monday-Thursday in this example)
    }
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anilk/G6K6Y/1549/) with ver 2.3.2 of fullCalendar

refer details [here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/businessHours/) and [here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Duration/) and finally [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/)

Comment: I tried the above code but it is still allowing me to click & add a new event.

Comment: businessHours is available after Ver 2.x, which version are you using?

Comment: Im using ver.2.x, well if i update your working fiddle with select property it allows me to click on all the non-business hours:  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
editable: true,
select:function(){
alert("Clicked");
},
events: "JsonResponse.ashx",

Comment: You have business hours configured, overtime is possible, clicking in not  omitted on business hours,  you should manage the business hours selection in select:function()

Comment: Thanks for your help Anil.

Comment: Downvoted, nothing about this works as described.  You can click on the greyed out dates, and the non-greyed out dates (in week and day view) it doesn't even let you click in those ranges.